# How do sum a value with the previous row value for a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the first two rows look like this:

```
             GOOG    AAPL    XOM    IBM      Cash
2009-01-14    0.0   150.0    0.0    0.0  -12745.5
2009-01-15    0.0     0.0    0.0    0.0      -0.0
```

I want it to add in the previous rows value for each row. So I would want it to look like this:

```
             GOOG    AAPL    XOM    IBM      Cash
2009-01-14    0.0   150.0    0.0    0.0  -12745.5
2009-01-15    0.0   150.0    0.0    0.0      -0.0
```

I do not want it to affect the cash column.

Is there a way to do this easily in pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) only for filtered columns by [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
c = df.columns.difference(['Cash'])
df[c] = df[c].cumsum()
print (df)
            GOOG   AAPL  XOM  IBM     Cash
2009-01-14   0.0  150.0  0.0  0.0 -12745.5
2009-01-15   0.0  150.0  0.0  0.0     -0.0
```

Or by condition with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
c = df.columns != 'Cash'
df.loc[:, c] = df.loc[:, c].cumsum()
```